# How to get image source of first image with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

In the following code, I want the first image to be displayed when the page loads, however, it doesn't show anything, and no error in Firebug.

How can I get this line to work:

```
$('img#main').attr('src', $('img:first').src);
```

**Full Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load('jquery', '1.5');
            google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {

                $('img.thm').css({opacity: 0.7});
                $('img#main').attr('src', $('img:first').src); //doesn't work

                $('img.thm').width(80).click(function() {
                    $('img#main').attr('src', this.src);
                });
                $('img.thm').mouseover(function() {
                    $(this).css({opacity: 1.0});
                });
                $('img.thm').mouseout(function() {
                    $(this).css({opacity: 0.7});
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            img.thm {
                cursor: hand;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <img class="thm" src="images/test1.png"/>
            <img class="thm" src="images/test2.png"/>
            <img class="thm" src="images/test3.png"/>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <img id="main"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `.attr()` when getting the image source from `$('img:first')` which is a jQuery object:

```
$('img#main').attr('src', $('img:first').attr('src'));
```

The `.src` property is for the DOM object representing the image. You could use it like this (see [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get)):

```
$('img#main').attr('src', $('img').get(0).src);
```

But for consistency's sake I would use `.attr()`.

Answer (score 5):

`$('img').first().attr('src')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img#main').attr('src', $('img:first').attr('src'));
```