# Getting image source from first image within a specific content div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the src attribute out of the first image that is within the #main-content div in my website. It's nested in quite deep and many other stackoverflow examples I have seen are more simple and don't match my requirements. Closest I found was [How to get image source of first image with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241585/how-to-get-image-source-of-first-image-with-jquery)

The image I am trying to target does not have an ID, and won't have one applied. Here is the HTML code pattern (this is the segment not complete page code):

```
<div id="main-content">
  <div id="gallery-type-2">
    <div class="gallery-image">
      <img src="images/my-image.png" alt="my image" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now this code is very simplified and there is many types of page templates within the website but the common pattern I am looking for is the first image under the #main-content.

jQuery code I am trying to use is:

```
var postImage = $('#main-content img').first().attr('src');
console.log(postImage);
```

The inspector keeps coming back with undefined. I've tried doing it as an array [0] but not having any luck there either.

Comment: have u tried using `closest()`?

Comment: Why are you not using id?

Comment: No I'm unfamiliar with that command. I don't think I have used it before.

Comment: Your code looks fine. It's an environment problem. U can try some other implement,eg:`$('#main-content img:first').attr('src')`

Comment: @gu jefers, I did that code before I switched to my example above. Had the same result

Comment: @AfshanShujat, I would love to target via an image ID but the site I am working on is so large (thousands and thousands of pages), I can't go in and retrospectively add image ids to every image. The purpose of what I am doing is trying to find a suitable image for sharing with Open Graph metadata. I am working off the only stable pattern I can find.

Comment: Wow, both methods I actually used (variants of the :first) did work. Issue is I was testing on a page that used lazy load images. This particular page will fail on this script and I will have to setup some fallback logic (when undefined) to display a generic org image.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```js
 $("#main-content").find("img:first").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-content">
  <div id="gallery-type-2">
    <div class="gallery-image">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJtQG.png?s=32&g=1" alt="my image" />
    </div>
     <div class="gallery-image">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJtQG.png?s=32&g=1" alt="my image" />
    </div>
     <div class="gallery-image">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJtQG.png?s=32&g=1" alt="my image" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not completely sure what you are suggesting there Mark but I applied the '.find' syntaxt to my code and got the same result: var mytidbit = $("#main-content").find("img:first").attr("src");

Answer (score 0):

This works fine with `jQuery` included.

```js
var postImage = $('#main-content img').first().attr('src');
console.log(postImage);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-content">
    <div id="gallery-type-2">
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="images/my-image.png" alt="my image" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I just now noticed that I was trying to pull an image from a lazy load gallery which is obviously not allowing the image source code to be read at load time (*slaps forehead*). Hey does anyone know how to then get the variable into an open graph metadata tag's content attribute?